# How to perform crop settings in TypoScript?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm using `TYPO3 7` and want to apply the crop settings of the `media` field in this `TypoScript` snippet:

```
lib.backgroundimage = FILES 
lib.backgroundimage {
    references.data =  levelmedia:-1, slide
    references.listNum = 0
    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
    renderObj.altText.data = file:current:description
    renderObj.file {
        import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        width = 1920
        height = 600c
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`crop.data = file:current:crop` is the key

your complete code:

```
lib.backgroundimage = FILES 
    lib.backgroundimage {
    references.data =  levelmedia:-1, slide
    references.listNum = 0
    renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
    renderObj.altText.data = file:current:description
    renderObj.file {
        import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        crop.data = file:current:crop
        width = 1920
        height = 600c
    }
}
```

Comment: in TYPO3 8, the width and height settings will override the crop data. I need it the other way round, that width & height are only fallback. Any hints?

Comment: I've posted the question here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584655/use-cropped-image-with-fallback-in-typoscript-in-typo3-8

Answer (score -2):

try `file.import.data = file:current:uid` as used in CSS Styled content.
Also see the documentation about this which states that the crop setting is automatically imported: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/7.2/Feature-65584-AddImageCropping.html